MAUI and LocalNotifications: recurring notification is not working
In my NET8 MAUI, I'm using the plugin Plugin.LocalNotification. I set a notification to be repeated daily with this code:
INotificationService _notificationService;

var notifyDateTime = 
    DateTime.Parse($"{DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()} 08:00:00");
var notification = new NotificationRequest
{
    NotificationId = 100,
    Title = AppResources.NotificationsTitle,
    Description = AppResources.NotificationDescription,
    CategoryType = NotificationCategoryType.Status,
    Schedule =
    {
        NotifyTime = notifyDateTime,
        RepeatType = NotificationRepeat.Daily
    }
};

await _notificationService.Show(notification);

The notification is fired once and then nothing. I thought the notification would stay there until the cancellation and fired daily. Do I have to resend the notification again every time it is fired?
I added in the MauiProgram.cs the following lines
var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
builder
    .UseMauiApp<App>()
    .........
    .UseLocalNotification();

For the other settings, I followed the documentation. In the AndroidManifest.xml I added the following lines
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM" />

The issue I had was with the Google Play. When I submitted the app with those settings, Google rejected my app because it is not an agenda or a calendar.

And you are absolutely sure you added all setup code?

I added in the MauiProgram.cs under builder the UseLocalNotification(). I add the component like in the documentation https://github.com/thudugala/Plugin.LocalNotification/wiki/1.-Usage-10.0.0--.Net-MAUI

I have tried that before, sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't, perhaps, you'd think about services, till this library get improved.

@Enrico did you manipulate the manifest in one of the ways specified in the docs?

Awww yes. Well, Google was trying to introduce the strict discipline of Apple lately, by randomly copying rules that IOS developers have followed for years. The end result is questionable. And your code starts to look like "if version == ... else if ... else if...". I am so lucky that most of my apps get distributed by different channels. Or have elevated privileges...
